# Problem when insert a list in a DataFrame, one column disappears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert a list into a DataFrame.
The list shows this information:

**row_list**

```
[{'Número': 51,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'EDITAL 51/2019 – PPGIELA - HOMOLOGAÇÃO E RESULTADO FINAL - PROCESSO SELETIVO PARA ALUNOS(AS) REGULARES 2020',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Ingresso discentes',
  'Unidade responsável': 'PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-IELA',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '09-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '09-12-2019'},
 {'Número': 50,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'EDITAL 50/2019 – PPGIELA - RESULTADO DOS RECURSOS IMPETRADOS FRENTE AO RESULTADO FINAL PRELIMINAR DO PROCESSO SELETIVO 2020',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Ingresso discentes',
  'Unidade responsável': 'PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-IELA',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '09-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '09-12-2019'},
 {'Número': 7,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'homologação do resultado preliminar do Processo Eleitoral para a escolha dos(as) COORDENADORES(AS) e VICE-COORDENADORES(AS) dos CENTROS INTERDISCIPLINARES do Instituto Latino-Americano de Economia, Sociedade e Política',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Eleições',
  'Unidade responsável': 'Comissão Eleitoral Local - ILAESP',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '09-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '09-12-2019'},
 {'Número': 48,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'Resultado final do processo seletivo de alunos regulares, para ingresso no curso de mestrado em Biociências, no primeiro semestre letivo do ano de 2020',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Pós-Graduação',
  'Unidade responsável': 'PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-BC',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '09-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '09-12-2019'},
 {'Número': 101,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'Processo de seleção PIBIC, PIBITI e PIVICTI 2020/2021',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Pesquisa',
  'Unidade responsável': 'PRPPG',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '09-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '09-12-2019'},
 {'Número': 181,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'RESULTADO FINAL - PROCESSO SELETIVO DE VAGAS OCIOSAS – 2020 - REOPÇÃO DE CURSO (exceto Medicina), REINGRESSO (exceto Medicina), TRANSFERÊNCIA, E APROVEITAMENTO DE DIPLOMA',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Graduação',
  'Unidade responsável': 'PROGRAD',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '07-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '07-12-2019'},
 {'Número': 47,
  'Ano': 2019,
  'Descrição': 'Resultado preliminar do processo seletivo de alunos regulares, para ingresso no curso de mestrado em Biociências, no primeiro semestre letivo do ano de 2020',
  'Conteúdo novo?': 'novo',
  'Tipo': 'Pós-Graduação',
  'Unidade responsável': 'PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-BC',
  'Retificação': 'Não',
  'Data de publicação': '06-12-2019',
  'Data de atualização': '09-12-2019'}]
```

I insert the list in the DataFrame:

**df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)**

But when i print the df i get one column missing:

```
Ano Conteúdo novo? Data de atualização Data de publicação                ...                 Número  Retificação                Tipo                Unidade responsável
0  2019           novo          09-12-2019         09-12-2019                ...                     51          Não  Ingresso discentes             PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-IELA
1  2019           novo          09-12-2019         09-12-2019                ...                     50          Não  Ingresso discentes             PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-IELA
2  2019           novo          09-12-2019         09-12-2019                ...                      7          Não            Eleições  Comissão Eleitoral Local - ILAESP
3  2019           novo          09-12-2019         09-12-2019                ...                     48          Não       Pós-Graduação               PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-BC
4  2019           novo          09-12-2019         09-12-2019                ...                    101          Não            Pesquisa                              PRPPG
5  2019           novo          07-12-2019         07-12-2019                ...                    181          Não           Graduação                            PROGRAD
6  2019           novo          09-12-2019         06-12-2019                ...                     47          Não       Pós-Graduação               PÓS-GRADUAÇÃO PPG-BC
```

The column **'Descrição':** is replacd by **...**

I research but dont find out what is the problem...

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure its missing? If you do dataframe.column, do you see the column come up?

Comment: I guess you meant to say ```df.columns```.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your column still there. The ellipsis is just the way pandas uses to present you the dataframe. You can see your column still there with ```df.columns``` and you can access your data with ```df.Descrição```.

Comment: im able to see using `df.columns`

Comment: I think is just your console ...when you print

Comment: try add this :             pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

Comment: How im able to show all, because every time im try to convert in string `message = str(df2)` to be able to send by email im get the "missing column"

Comment: wait, are you trying send this information (df) by email ??

Comment: Yes!!! 
How crazy is this idea? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203945/discussion-between-elmor3no-and-giovanisalazar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a visualization issue, try these settings at the beginning of your code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Comment: This `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 200)` solve the issue

Comment: @elMor3no great!